Allure doesn't capture screenshots in Listener
public class ScreenshotUtility {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public ScreenshotUtility(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @Attachment(value = "Screenshot for {0}", type = "image/png")
    public byte[] captureScreenshot(String testName) {

        if (driver == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Driver is null. Cannot take screenshot.");
        }

        try{
            TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
            byte[] screenshotBytes = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    
            File srcFile = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            String screenshotDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/allure-results/";
            File destFile = new File(screenshotDir + "scr_" + testName + ".png");
            File parentDir = destFile.getParentFile();
            if(parentDir != null && !parentDir.exists()) {
                parentDir.mkdirs();
            }

        FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, destFile);
        System.out.println("Screenshot saved: " + destFile.getAbsolutePath());

        FileInputStream screenshotStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(srcFile);
        Allure.addAttachment("Page Screenshot", screenshotStream);
        
        return screenshotBytes;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Error taking screenshot: " + e.getMessage());
            return new byte[0];
        }
    }
}

public class TestListener implements ITestListener {

    private ScreenshotUtility screenshotUtility;

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println("[ERROR] Test failed: " + result.getName());
        System.out.println("[ERROR] Exception: " + result.getThrowable());
        try{
        Object testClass = result.getInstance();
        if (testClass instanceof BaseTest) {
        WebDriver driver = ((BaseTest) testClass).getDriver();
            if(driver != null) {
                screenshotUtility = new ScreenshotUtility(driver);
                screenshotUtility.captureScreenshot(result.getName()); 
                System.out.println("Screenshot is ready: " + result.getName());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("[ERROR] Driver is null.");
                }
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.out.println("[ERROR] Unable to take a screenshot: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public class BaseTest {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected WebDriverWait wait;
    protected BasePage basePage;
    protected ScreenshotUtility screenshotUtility;
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        driver = DriverFactory.getDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        basePage = new BasePage(driver);
        screenshotUtility = new ScreenshotUtility(driver);
    }

    @AfterMethod()
        public void tearDown(ITestResult result) {
        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            try{
                screenshotUtility.captureScreenshot(result.getName());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                System.err.println("[ERROR] Unable to take a screenshot: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            }
        windowManager.switchFrameToDefaultContent();
    
        if (driver != null) {
            try {
                driver.quit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                driver = null; 
            }
        }


@Listeners(TestListener.class)
@Epic("Blabla")
public class TestClass extends BaseTest {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Feature("Feature")
    @Story("Story")
    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        <code>

In safe allure, Epic, Story, Feature and a screenshot from the class: BaseTest: @AfterMethod - TearDown are properly stored.
Screenshots from class: TestListener are not saved.
I don't know what to do, wrong. The system already works on various systems. And he escaped to leave the screenshot to allure after the failed test, not after defeating the method.
Please help.
JDK: 21, apache-maven-3.9.9, selenium: 4.25.0, allure: 2.29.0, testNG: 7.10.2, VSCode
I tried to take screenshots in various places. I expect that after an incorrect test, the listener will write a message and upload a screenshot to the allure report.*
When I do:
@Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        // WebDriver driver = null;
        try {
            Object instance = result.getInstance();
            if (instance instanceof BaseTest) {
            WebDriver driver = ((BaseTest) instance).getDriver();
                if (driver != null) {

                    screenshotUtility = new ScreenshotUtility(driver);
                    String testName = result.getName();
                    screenshotUtility.captureScreenshot(testName);              

                    String errorMessage = result.getThrowable().getMessage();
                    Allure.addAttachment("Error Message", errorMessage);
            ...
        }
    }

the driver is found, and is the same as in Base Test.
enter image description here
but there is still no screenshot in Allure

you should probably avoid hard-coding the "/" there.  Instead use File.separator.  Ex:  String screenshotDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "allure-results" + File.separator;     Also not sure why you are getting bytes, and also the file.  You don't seem to be using the bytes, so you should probably remove that call and return void.  The main problem is the way this framework is designed and trying to get instances from static classes... see this thread for solution(s): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50347922/how-to-get-the-current-class-driver-in-itestlistener

I changed what you wrote and tried the solution from the attached stackoverflow, but nothing helped.

Is anyone able to help me?
